# Structuring a SQL statement to display by two levels depth not one upwards

Tags: sql

```
SELECT parent.name 
FROM categories AS node,
categories AS parent,
categories AS parent1
WHERE node.left_node > parent.left_node AND node.right_node < parent.right_node AND parent.left_node > parent1.left_node AND < parent.right_node > parent1.right_node
AND node.name = '{$node_name}'
ORDER BY parent.right_node DESC
```

The query above will display all the parents to the root of the node called. I only want to get the next parent not all the way to the root, but only node above. For instance in the graphic below

http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/7139/fruittree.gif

I want to pull up FOOD when RED called Or Fruit when Cherry is called. For that I have created three level AS node, parent and parent1. Condition according to its values in the right and the left. I want to  pull up those fields only WHERE node.left_node > parent.left_node AND node.right_node < parent.right_node AND parent.left_node > parent1.left_node AND < parent.right_node > parent1.right_node
AND node.name = '{$node_name}'.

Don't know if the Condition it would be the right one in this case because it is throwing a fatal error with that query above.

any opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original query you just need to do the following modifications:

```
SELECT parent1.name
FROM categories AS node,
categories AS parent,
categories AS parent1
WHERE node.left_node > parent.left_node AND node.right_node < parent.right_node
  AND parent.left_node > parent1.left_node AND parent.right_node < parent1.right_node
  AND node.name = '{$node_name}'
ORDER BY parent.right_node DESC
```

Comment: Great query, When you mean revert the order is to get the top would be ORDER BY node.right_node, Also I don't see you use the AS x alias in the SELECTS why? right now the query is only returning a level above the $node_name I want it to go to FOOD if RED was called right now Is pulling Fruit one level depth. I changed the limits in the outsie SELECT with not avail.

Comment: I modified my solution. Now your original query needs only slight changes. The `ORDER BY` bit doesn't affect the result, so I just removed it.

Comment: I just got a blank page Andriy with the original query and ORDER BY, I print_r the variable which supposedly is containing the data for parent1.name but it will come out empty.

Comment: This is the php object oriented code which return the function with the query   $hierachy = new hierachy;
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new recursiveArrayIterator($hierachy->singlePathroot2($name1)));
try {
print_r($iterator);
    foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
        {
        if ($key <> "depth")
        echo $value.'<br />';
        }
    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  
  }

Comment: this query above should work, all the conditions if met could print the level of FOOD if Red or YELLOW is specify, the same if Cherry is specify then it would return FRUIT but instead it is returning empty. I don't know if it is the php then, I am using RecursiveIteratorIterator() and recursiveArrayIterator() functions for this, I don't think it is waiting for an array of value really becuase there will only be one parent1 I will try taking out the recursiveArrayIterator () function

Comment: I checked my solution in SQL Server and it did work for me. That is actually why I said `ORDER BY` was unnecessary. For I wouldn't have been so sure about that if I hadn't received the evidence from actually running the script. You might probably want to verify the query yourself, outside your PHP code. Then you would know for sure whether the problem is with the PHP code or with the query.

Comment: Guys we made to return it two levels up or grandparent, We needed an ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1 without ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1 it was returning other level above two levels but with this it stop at two levels...................... YEA finally. Andriy I tested and it was close.

Comment: It is working like a charm in SQL testing box, but in my php it is throwing an error, this is the function public function singlePathroot2($node_name){
$stmt = conn::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT parent1.name
FROM categories AS node,
categories AS parent,
categories AS parent1
WHERE node.left_node > parent.left_node AND node.right_node < parent.right_node
  AND parent.left_node > parent1.left_node AND parent.right_node < parent1.right_node
  AND node.name = '{$node_name}'
  ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1
 
");
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

Comment: The instantiation of this function in another page is like  $hierachy = new hierachy;
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new recursiveArrayIterator($hierachy->singlePathroot2($name1)));
try {
    foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
        {
        if ($key <> "depth")
        echo $value.'<br />';
        }
    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  
  }

Comment: Now we know the Query is working but some how with the php structure is trowing an error the error is     Parents 

    Sibilins 

    Children 

    Grandchildren 

    Cousins 

    Newphews 

 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE node.left_node > parent.left_node AND node.right_node < parent.right_node ' at line 4' in public_html/parent/scripts/functions.php:97